# intersect_line_plane not returning location as expected

Tags: python

I'm trying to get an object to move around under the mouse cursor, but remain locked to a plane in 3D space. The following code is called with a previously found face from a `ray_cast` call passing the hit faces location and normal as `plane_loc, plane_dir`.

I'm expecting `mathutils.geometry.intersect_line_plane` to work like this:

1. Find a line between the mouse cursor and the location the ray hits
2. Make a plane from the `plane_loc, plane_dir` arguments
3. Return the intersection point of the line and plane
4. Move the object `self.pointer` to that point

The issue is that I'm expecting the object to stay under the mouse cursor, visibly on the screen, which it does as long as the mouse remains over the original faces plane that was used to gather `plane_loc, plane_dir`, but when the mouse moves over any other face the object drifts away from the cursor, as you can see in the video.

If the line used by `intersect_line_plane` truly is between the mouse cursor and the face directly beneath it, the intersection point should always be directly under the cursor, or so I believe. What am I missing?

[image]

```
def pointer_to_mouse_plane(self, context, event, plane_loc, plane_dir):
    # keep pointer on mouse during sectioning, but locked to section plane
    region = context.region
    rv3d = context.region_data
    coord = event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y
    view_vector = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d(region, rv3d, coord)

    self.pointer.hide_viewport = True
    hit, location, normal, index, object, face_matrix = self.cast_ray(context, event)

    if hit:
        loc_on_plane = mathutils.geometry.intersect_line_plane(location, view_vector, plane_loc, plane_dir)
        print("mouse_to_pointer_plane:", loc_on_plane)
        print("location:", location)
        self.pointer.location = loc_on_plane
        self.pointer.hide_viewport = False

def cast_ray(self, context, event):
    # cast ray from mouse location, return data from ray
    scene = context.scene
    region = context.region
    rv3d = context.region_data
    coord = event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y
    viewlayer = context.view_layer
    # get the ray from the viewport and mouse
    view_vector = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d(region, rv3d, coord)
    ray_origin = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_origin_3d(region, rv3d, coord)

    hit, location, normal, index, object, matrix = scene.ray_cast(viewlayer, ray_origin, view_vector)

    if hit:
        return hit, location, normal, index, object, matrix
```

Comment: i am not sure because you didn't show us the "whole" working code, but maybe your plane_loc, plane_dir isn't updated in the not shown code? it's just a guess...

Comment: The full code is 650 lines... And mostly irrelevant. I used `plane_loc, plane_dir` to draw edges in a new object that is perfectly in line with the viewport angle. `plane_loc, plane_dir` comes from another call to the same `cast_ray` function using its returned `location, normal` values.